# Restoring System after crash fails (Ubuntu Budgie 20.04)

Tags: ubuntu, restore

My ubuntu  20.04 crashed and now the computer only boots into grub rescue mode. As usual, i wanted to repair Ubuntu with fsck. But the df output doesnt list my hard drives /dev/sda and /dev/sdb. The output looks like in the attached screenshot. And sorry for adding it as a picture, copy+paste destroyed the formatting of the table.

Do you have an idea how to restore the OS?

[image: df output]

Here is the output of cat and fdisk (shortened to the important hard drive).

[image: cat output]

[image: fdisk output]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be better to mention and explain reseon of crash.

Comment: Well, when i go into hibernation/sleep mode with Ubuntu, the OS can't wake up again. Then i have to long press the power button to switch it off. I accidentally pressed the hibernate button instead of power off -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the OS cannot mount the partition, it won't be visible with `df`.
You can see which are the available partitions with

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

or (as root)

```
fdisk -l
```

Keep in mind you don't have to pass whole disks (i.e. <del>sda</del> or <del>sdb</del>) to `fsck`, but the specific partition (i.e.: `sda1` or `sdb1`)

Comment: It worked. I could fsck my /dev/sdb4 now. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: You can probably flag the answer as the accepted one, or mark it as useful (the "up" arrow), so to be easier to who finds this question